# sockets.io.js module not found

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I am currently working on a website project using javascript. I am unable to call the `socket.io` module, which I installed using `npm install socket.io`.

I tried to use it in the HTML script:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But I got an error, apparently because the module is not found.

I didn't find any other way to install it on the internet. Does anyone know a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: You can use the [CDN version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.dev.js). Most likely this is a path issue, what are you using as backend? express and node? We need some more info here.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `npm install socket.io`, the *socked.io* library is installed to a special directory called *node_modules*.

In your HTML file, you are trying to load the library from a path that expects it to be located in a subdirectory called `socket.io` in the public documents directory of your server.

You have three options:

- copy the `socket.io` library to a directory where your server can serve it and the browser can find it
- adjust the path in your script tag to point to `node_modules/socket.io`
- load `socket.io` from a CDN, for example:

  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>`

I would recommend the third option.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it globally using `-g` parameter:

```
npm install -g socket.io
```

If you don't want to do the above then you need to run the project using local node_modules dependencies. To do that:

1. Add the following alias in ~/.bashrc `alias npm-exec='PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH'`
2. Run all npm commands by prefixing `npm-exec` to use local node modules
3. Example: `npm-exec npm build`